# Criando Report Dentro de uma panel

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fast-reports

Estou precisando exibir um relatório numa determinaria área do sistema( na metade direira)

ja na metade esquerda quero colocar outros componentes( como botões de modo e exibição e outras opções para impressão)

Como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No evento onpreview do report coloque:

```
 var
   frmPreview: TfrxPreviewForm;
begin
  inherited;
   Relatorio.PreviewOptions.Modal   := False;
   Relatorio.EngineOptions.DestroyForms := True;
//   Relatorio.PreviewOptions.Buttons := [pbPrint,pbLoad,pbSave,pbExport,pbZoom,pbFind,pbOutline,pbPageSetup,pbTools,pbNavigator,pbExportQuick,pbNoClose,pbNoFullScreen];
   Relatorio.PreviewForm.Align := alClient;
   frmPreview := TfrxPreviewForm(Relatorio.PreviewForm);
   frmPreview.BorderStyle := bsNone;
   frmPreview.Left:=0;
   frmPreview.Top:=0;
   frmPreview.Width:=pRelatorio.ClientWidth;
   frmPreview.Height:=pRelatorio.ClientHeight;
   frmPreview.Parent:=pRelatorio;
```

Onde pRelatorio é name do panel.